# Trying to seed dev db for Diaspora, bcrypt seg faults. Mac OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, diaspora

I'm trying to run rake db:seed:dev on a developer instance of Diaspora https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki and I get a bcrypt-ruby segmentation fault error. I've looked around and am unable to find any info relating to bcrypt-ruby and segmentation faults. Anyone have any ideas or know whats going on? I'm actually new to Ruby as well.

```
Seeding the database for development...
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2/lib/bcrypt.rb:50: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i386-darwin10.5.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0049 p:---- s:0185 b:0185 l:000184 d:000184 CFUNC  :__bc_crypt
c:0048 p:0137 s:0179 b:0179 l:000178 d:000178 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2/lib/bcrypt.rb:50
c:0047 p:0038 s:0173 b:0173 l:000172 d:000172 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/encryptors/bcrypt.rb:11
c:0046 p:0075 s:0166 b:0166 l:000165 d:000165 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:86
c:0045 p:0061 s:0162 b:0160 l:000159 d:000159 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:41
c:0044 p:0051 s:0156 b:0156 l:000146 d:000155 BLOCK  /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:183
c:0043 p:---- s:0152 b:0152 l:000151 d:000151 FINISH
c:0042 p:---- s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 CFUNC  :each_pair
c:0041 p:0030 s:0147 b:0147 l:000146 d:000146 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:181
c:0040 p:0020 s:0143 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:211
c:0039 p:0023 s:0138 b:0138 l:000137 d:000137 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/accessible.rb:21
c:0038 p:0023 s:0134 b:0134 l:000133 d:000133 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/protected.rb:30
c:0037 p:0036 s:0130 b:0130 l:000129 d:000129 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:165
c:0036 p:0012 s:0126 b:0126 l:000125 d:000125 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:14
c:0035 p:0012 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/sci.rb:26
c:0034 p:0016 s:0118 b:0118 l:000117 d:000117 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/callbacks.rb:7
c:0033 p:---- s:0114 b:0114 l:000113 d:000113 FINISH
c:0032 p:---- s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 CFUNC  :new
c:0031 p:0023 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD /Users/jonathanmccall2/diaspora/app/models/user.rb:387
c:0030 p:0270 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 TOP    /Users/jonathanmccall2/diaspora/db/seeds/dev.rb:25
c:0029 p:---- s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 FINISH
c:0028 p:---- s:0094 b:0094 l:000093 d:000093 CFUNC  :require
c:0027 p:0012 s:0090 b:0090 l:000074 d:000089 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239
c:0026 p:0005 s:0088 b:0088 l:000079 d:000087 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225
c:0025 p:0045 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591
c:0024 p:0041 s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225
c:0023 p:0013 s:0075 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239
c:0022 p:0058 s:0070 b:0070 l:000d74 d:000069 BLOCK  /Users/jonathanmccall2/diaspora/lib/tasks/db.rake:15
c:0021 p:---- s:0068 b:0068 l:000067 d:000067 FINISH
c:0020 p:---- s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 CFUNC  :call
c:0019 p:0043 s:0061 b:0061 l:000052 d:000060 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634
c:0018 p:---- s:0058 b:0058 l:000057 d:000057 FINISH
c:0017 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 CFUNC  :each
c:0016 p:0171 s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629
c:0015 p:0110 s:0049 b:0049 l:000043 d:000048 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595
c:0014 p:0019 s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0013 p:0033 s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588
c:0012 p:0048 s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581
c:0011 p:0045 s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041
c:0010 p:0012 s:0026 b:0026 l:000011 d:000025 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019
c:0009 p:---- s:0023 b:0023 l:000022 d:000022 FINISH
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 CFUNC  :each
c:0007 p:0069 s:0018 b:0018 l:000011 d:000017 BLOCK  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019
c:0006 p:0009 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058
c:0005 p:0011 s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013
c:0004 p:0031 s:0009 b:0009 l:000008 d:000008 METHOD /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992
c:0003 p:0036 s:0006 b:0006 l:000b94 d:0002a4 EVAL   /usr/local/bin/rake:31
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000b94 d:000b94 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/diaspora/lib/tasks/db.rake:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/diaspora/db/seeds/dev.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/diaspora/app/models/user.rb:387:in `build'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/diaspora/app/models/user.rb:387:in `new'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/callbacks.rb:7:in `initialize'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/sci.rb:26:in `initialize'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:14:in `initialize'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:165:in `initialize'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/protected.rb:30:in `assign'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/accessible.rb:21:in `assign'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:211:in `assign'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:181:in `attributes='
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:181:in `each_pair'
/Users/jonathanmccall2/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/mongomapper-de8f8f3171f6/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:183:in `block in attributes='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:41:in `password='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:86:in `password_digest'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.3/lib/devise/encryptors/bcrypt.rb:11:in `digest'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2/lib/bcrypt.rb:50:in `hash_secret'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.2/lib/bcrypt.rb:50:in `__bc_crypt'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing and then re-installing the bcrypt-ruby gem. I'm too new to Ruby myself to tell you why, but I ran into the same seg fault on OS X several times when starting new RoR projects (running under RVM with project-specific gemsets), and removing+re-installing bcrypt-ruby resolved it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use RVM to install ruby 1.9.2 and try again.  I had nothing but problems with ruby 1.9.1.

Comment: Hey I installed RVM and tried installing ruby 1.9.2 but got a make error...

    85 make: *** [libruby.1.9.1.dylib] Error 1